# Opening Googlemaps App to a Specific Location

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps

I am trying to open Gogole Maps to a specific location with the below code, however the app is crashing with the error "No Activity Found to Handle Intent". Can anyone see what the problem is ?

```
ImageButton addressbutton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.addressbutton);

        addressbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {        
        String uri = "geo:0,0?q=MCNAMARA+TERMINAL+ROMULUS+MI+48174";        
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse(uri));
        startActivity(i); 
        }
    });
```

Comment: I pasted your onClick code in a test project of mine and it worked fine. Which API are you targetting?  My test project targetted Google 1.6 (API Level 4).

Comment: Per Tomik's answer below, is it Android 2.2 or Google 2.2?

Comment: Android 2.2 - I don't understand the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code works fine. The problem is the device/emulator you are testing the code at.

If you use AVD having Google APIs target (any level since 3), it works as expected. However, if you use AVD having normal Android target (that's a target without maps support), you get the error.

Comment: Thanks - so it's only possible to test map view on Google API target ?

Comment: To test maps application you need Google API deployment target. And if you want to use MapView widget in your activity layout, you also have to add <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" /> to your manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this:

```
intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
```

before the call to `startActivity`.

HTH

Comment: Changes error message to "unable to find explicit class for com.google.android....."

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(uri));
```

instead of

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
```

Comment: gives compiler error that constructor (string,string) is undefined.